# Finding text from html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following .html:

```
<li class="print text">
                            <span><em class="time">
                                    <div class="time">1.29 s</div>
                                </em><em class="status">passed</em>This is the text I want to get</span>
```

I need to get only the text that is outside all of the other tags (text is: This is the text I want to get).

I was trying to use this piece of code:

```
for el in doc.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'print text'}):
    print(el.get_text())
```

But unfortunatelly it prints everything including the em tags etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: you can replace the em tags with a blank string using he `.replace()` method of the returned string... but we need more details.. the whole code woulkd be better

Comment: @PrakharParikh Which code do you mean? .html or python?

Comment: I meant the python code.... but if you can provided both. it would be better than enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with `find(text=True, recursive=False)` to get your goal.

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup='''<li class="print text">
        <span><em class="time">
                <div class="time">1.29 s</div>
            </em><em class="status">passed</em>This is the text I want to get</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(soup)

soup.find('li',class_='print text').span.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

##### Output

```
This is the text I want to get
```

---

If there are multiple `span` in your `li` you could go with:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup='''<li class="print text">
        <span><em class="time">
                <div class="time">1.29 s</div>
            </em><em class="status">passed</em>This is the text I want to get</span>
            <span><em class="time">
                <div class="time">1.50 s</div>
            </em><em class="status">passed</em>This is the text I want to get too</span>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(soup)

for e in soup.select('li.print.text span'):
    print(e.find(text=True, recursive=False))
```

###### Output

```
This is the text I want to get
This is the text I want to get too
```

Answer (score 2):

Find specific `li` tag with `class` and use `find_all` method on `em` tag to get the last tag from list using indexing and `next-sibling` method return text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup="""<li class="print text">
        <span><em class="time">
                <div class="time">1.29 s</div>
            </em><em class="status">passed</em>This is the text I want to get</span>"""

soup=BeautifulSoup(soup)
soup.find("li",class_="print text").find_all("em")[-1].next_sibling
```

Comment: Thank you!! This one works, but is there a way to do this for multiple spans? Imagine I have this in my html file multiple times, how do I make it so it works for all of it? I tried chaning it to soup.find_all("li",class_="print text").find_all("em")[-1].next_sibling, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Never mind, I figured this one out by myself. Thank you!